# CSS Style not getting applied to a series in Highchart

Tags: css, extjs, highcharts

I am trying to change color of a series in Highcharts using a CSS. But it doesn't work. It shows some default colors.
Below is my extjs code where i have defined my series:

```
                        series : [
                        {
                            name : "Cost Estimate Today",
                            cls : 'costToday',
                            data : [],
                            pointPadding : -0.05
                        }, {
                            name : "Cost Estimate Yesterday",
                            cls : 'costYesterday',
                            data : [],
                            pointPadding : -0.05,
                            dashStyle : 'dash'
                        }
                    ]
```

My CSS is defined as below:

```
.costToday
{
  color: #7ab800 !important; 
}

.costYesterday
{
  color: #e98300 !important; 
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to color, the text or the graph?

Comment: I want to color the graph (chart lines)

Comment: Then your approach will not work. The CSS color attribute applies to text. What you want is coloring an SVG path (I think, don't know much about Highcharts.)

Answer (score 2):

You can color parts of the graph if you point them in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/0jsa3fw6/

JS:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C',
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Cost Estimate Today",
            cls: 'costToday',
            data: [1, 2, 3],
            pointPadding: -0.05
        }, {
            name: "Cost Estimate Yesterday",
            cls: 'costYesterday',
            data: [10, 5, 8],
            pointPadding: -0.05,
            dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
g.highcharts-series:nth-child(3) > path:first-child {
stroke: #e98300 !important;
}
g.highcharts-series:nth-child(1) > path:first-child {
stroke: #7ab800 !important;
}
```